# Record voices separatly in Teamspeak 3

Tags: teamspeak

I would like to know if there is a way to record the voice of everyone separatly.

For example, I would have a file called Bob.mp3 where we only hear what Bob is saying. We would also have another file called Giorgio.mp3 where we only hear Giorgio talking. Same thing for everyone else in the channel.

Is it possible to do that in any way? With a plugin or not.

Comment: Record everything. Then use an audio editing program to assemble each voice. It's a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah but I would need to ask everyone to start a program to record their voice only which would be a lot of trouble. I would like an easier way than that.